# Using excel formula to pull date in from another column

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula

Column A has some arbitrary text. Column B has a date in YYYY/MM/DD format (imperative that I keep it that way).

Column D is where the formula is:

```
="SELECT * FROM MEETINGSCOPE..MEETING WHERE MEETINGNAME='"&A1&"' AND ARRIVALDATE="&B1&" UNION"
```

For some reason, I am getting a numeric value of the date rather than the date itself. How do I pull in the actual date in the same format that I currently have it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the date value also needs to be surrounded by single quotations in the SQL query, also you can use the `TEXT` worksheet function:

```
="SELECT * FROM MEETINGSCOPE.MEETING WHERE MEETINGNAME='"&A1&"' AND ARRIVALDATE='"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy/mm/dd")&"' UNION"
```

Comment: You are correct in the fact that I need single quotes when I run the query but the problem is still happening where excel changes my YYYY/MM/DD to a 5 digit numeric value.

Comment: Sorry, just updated after re-thinking through your question

Comment: Glad I could help!